# Multicast from docker to host's eth

Tags: networking, docker, iptables, multicast, forwarding

currently i am trying to send some multicast data from my docker's application throughout my host's eth2 host interface. i did use `--net=host` option in docker and this was working perfectly, and unfortunately since i need to open multiple instances that uses same port, its impossible for me to use net=host anymore. i have to go through the `bridged` mode of `docker0`

in my docker's interface i have `eth0` which is linked to my `docker0` as
10.101.131.60.

therefore i did : `route add -net 225.1.1.0/28 dev eth0` to pass all multicast packets that my app send to 225.1.1.0/28 to my eth0, which is connected to host as `docker0`.

therefore, i used wireshark to listen whether my application really throws the message packet to my `eth0` inside container, and it really does sending multicasts when i use wireshark inside container.

now throughout i also used wireshark to listen to my `docker0` and the packets were there. Now how do i "Forward all my multicast packets" throughout docker0 to my eth2? i used several iptables approach, but none of them seemed to be useful, perhaps that its being ignored?

any help would be appreciated... thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an IGMP proxy like this: https://sourceforge.net/projects/igmpproxy/

Good luck